# Why does creating a DataFrame fail with "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Category is not supported"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 1.4.0.

I am trying to classify a text document on two different categories: scientific or non-scientific.
I have an issue while defining the type: Category. I use these commands:

```
scala> case class LabeledText(id: Long, category: Category, text: String)
defined class LabeledText

scala> val data = Seq(LabeledText(0, Scientific, "hello world"), LabeledText(1, NonScientific, "witaj swiecie")).toDF
```

But, an error was appeared:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type Category is not supported.
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what are Scintific and NonScientific?

Comment: Those are two types of category. I am trying to classify a text document on scientific or non-scientific one.

Comment: can you update with those information in the quextion? it would help you to get answer quickly. the more clear and informative your question is the more quick to get an answer

Comment: I wanted you to define what is category type and how you created Scientific and nonScientific objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have used [Example — Text Classification](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-mllib/spark-mllib-pipelines-example-classification.html) that **I** wrote in an attempt to offer an example of `LogisticRegression` in Spark MLlib.

I deeply apologize for not finishing it (or at least checking it out for correctness).

The proper version should start around `case class Article(id: Long, topic: String, text: String)` and follow along.

The opening example with `case class LabeledText` is not correct as it uses `Category` type that I think I've never used properly.